# Zotac Nano uses lots of power while on standby and accesses USB stick - why?

Tags: uefi, acpi

I have a Zotac Nano mini PC with a UEFI firmware here.

I have noticed that when on "standby" it consumes a few Watt of power. To illustrate:

We start with the power supply disconnected (the power supply still burns 0.2W all on its own):

[image: Completely powered down]

We connect the power supply. The machine goes into a standby mode which burns 3.7W. I suppose this corresponds to [ACPI power state](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Configuration_and_Power_Interface#Power_states) S5, "Soft Off" *"Other components may remain powered so the computer can "wake" on input from the keyboard, clock, modem, LAN, or USB device."*

[image: Power supply connected]

Now it's getting interesting. I connect a USB stick (containing a Fedora Live CD image). The machine begins to query the USB stick relentlessly (as indicated by the flashing LED on the stick) and power consumption goes up to 4.3W:

[image: USB stick active]

If you then press the power button, it gives up on the USB again and returns to 3.4W usage:

[image: USB stick inactive]

Finally you can power it up fully, whereupon it consumes 20.3W:

[image: Powered up]

Question: what is it doing with the USB stick when in "soft off"? Shouldn't it just check it once, then immediately let it go again? Is this a firmware problem?

Comment: Completely off topic for ServerFault.

Comment: @Wesley Why so? Definitely something for sysadmins. Oh well.